# ValueError: invalid literal for float() Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, model-fitting

I'm building a simple neural network using keras.

Each element of the training data has 100 dimensions, and I'm reading the labels of the elements from a text file.

```
f = open('maleE', "rt")
labelsTrain = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
f.close()
```

The labels are strings that have this structure: number_text

To fit the model on the training data:

```
model.fit(train, labelsTrain, epochs= 20000, batch_size= 1350)
```

And I get the following error:

```
File "DNN.py", line 112, in <module>
    model.fit(train, labelsTrain, epochs=20000, batch_size=1350)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 867, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1598, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1183, in _fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2273, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1087, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
  File "/Users/renzo/PyEnvironments/tensorKeras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 225_sokode
```

The label is the element 279 from a list of 378 labels.

Comment: One of your inputs seems to have a character that is not a valid float number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, pick a unique name for each of your classes. I say this because I don't get what is the `number` in your class labels (if it is not same for each class, use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to just keep the `text`). Then you should encode your string labels. For example, see [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17516/how-to-deal-with-string-labels-in-multi-class-classification-with-keras) for One-hot encoding of labels.